# Best way to get Spring Bean info from context WIHOUT creating app context?

Tags: spring

I have a Spring (3.1.) app that has a large app-context.xml file.  There is a second very small stand-alone application that needs just a few parameters from one of the beans that are configured in that xml file.

Rather than that little application instantiating the whole application context (which builds a lot of connections, etc), I just want to read in the couple of configuration parameters that are contained in that file.

I could of course create a new smaller small-app-context.xml that only has the configuration i need or put those parameters in a properties file, but then I need to maintain that information in two places, which I am trying to avoid.  I know I could read in and parse the raw XML file (not exactly sure the most efficient way to do that).  However, I was hoping that Spring provides a nice way to do this but I haven't found it.

Does Spring provide a clean way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to maintain it in two places? Can't your main context file include it, or use the properties from it?

Comment: I think this question should be re-elaborated: you do not want to re-create the ApplicationContext but you wonder if Spring can provide a clean way.

Are the applications running in different JVMs?

Can you use a common Maven artifact storing the property files and use it as a dependency for both applications?

Perhaps you should clarify a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring you can have multiple configuration files.  So for the part that you would like to reuse you would create a smaller, self-contained config file.  It can remain in the original project and your app-context.xml can include it.  Then your new, small project could include the small config xml and you wouldn't need to maintain the information in two locations.

Answer (score 2):

> I could of course create a new smaller small-app-context.xml that only has the configuration i need or put those parameters in a properties file

I would agree that configuration belongs in a properties file. Not the application context file. You should not be maintaining the configuration in two places. You should have the configuration once in your properties file and then make that available to any contexts which require it.

Comment: You should mention the PropertyPlaceHolder